# Can we write $\int_a^b \vec A . \vec {dB}$ = $\vec A . \int_a^b \vec {dB}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, vector-spaces

I have a very basic doubt that if we can write
$$ \int_a^b \vec A . \vec {dB}  = \vec A . \int_a^b  \vec {dB} $$
Or else there are some conditions that sometimes we can and sometimes can't?

Note: It is dot product inside integral.

Comment: Take $A$ being a $2\times 2$ matrix and see what happen...

Comment: If $A$ a constant vector?  Vector field?  What?

Comment: I am not familiar with such type of calculation. I just want it for let us say where $\vec A$ just simply a function in 3D coordinate represented by unit vectors.

Comment: @Randall $\vec A$ can be a constant vector or a variable vector. I want to know for both.